# How to call a method using a parameter in Java 8?

Tags: java

I'm doing an exercise where I prompt the user to give me their operator of choice and two different numbers and then I output the result. I know I can easily do this exercise with a if else or a switch case however I'd really like to make it work this way. The problem is at my operator method, apparently in Java you can't pass in a parameter and use that parameter to call a method. Is there a way to make this work? If you were confused by the question I'd be glad to clarify.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class methods {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome, choose your operator, would you like to add, subtract, multiply, or divide?");
        String typeofOperator = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the first number: ");
        int firstNumber = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the second number: ");
        int secondNumber = sc.nextInt();
        operator(typeofOperator, firstNumber, secondNumber);
    }

    public static void operator(String typeofOperator, int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
        typeofOperator(firstNumber, secondNumber);
    }

    public static int add(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
        int answer = firstNumber + secondNumber;
        result(answer);
    }
    public static int subtract(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
        int answer = firstNumber - secondNumber;
        result(answer);
    }
    public static int multiply(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
        int answer = firstNumber * secondNumber;
        result(answer);
    }
    public static int divide(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
        int answer = firstNumber / secondNumber;
        result(answer);
    }
    public static void result(int result) {
        System.out.println("This is the result: " + result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related, but I think that the fact that subtract, multiply and divide are all implemented using `+` is probably a mistake...

Comment: This can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string

Answer (score 5):

Use map with functions. It will be in Java 8 style:

```
public class methods {

    private static Map<String, BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>> OPERATOR_MAP = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        OPERATOR_MAP.put("add", methods::add);
        OPERATOR_MAP.put("subtract", methods::subtract);
        OPERATOR_MAP.put("multiply", methods::multiply);
        OPERATOR_MAP.put("divide", methods::divide);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome, choose your operator, would you like to add, subtract, multiply, or divide?");
        String typeofOperator = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the first number: ");
        int firstNumber = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the second number: ");
        int secondNumber = sc.nextInt();
        operator(typeofOperator, firstNumber, secondNumber);
    }

    public static void operator(String typeofOperator, int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
        OPERATOR_MAP.get(typeofOperator).apply(firstNumber, secondNumber);
    }

    public static int add(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
        int answer = firstNumber + secondNumber;
        result(answer);
        return 0;
    }
    public static int subtract(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
        int answer = firstNumber - secondNumber;
        result(answer);
        return 0;
    }
    public static int multiply(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
        int answer = firstNumber * secondNumber;
        result(answer);
        return 0;
    }
    public static int divide(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
        int answer = firstNumber / secondNumber;
        result(answer);
        return 0;
    }
    public static void result(int result) {
        System.out.println("This is the result: " + result);
    }
}
```

Of course there is no checking that user can specify non existent operator.

UPDATE: added "return 0" to all operator methods to make code compilable. I just wanted to make minimal changes to the original code to specify way how to reach required functionality.

UPDATE2: If operator methods are not required then I'd like to write it simpler:

```
public class methods {

    private static Map<String, BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>> OPERATOR_MAP = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        OPERATOR_MAP.put("add", (x, y) -> x + y);
        OPERATOR_MAP.put("subtract", (x, y) -> x - y);
        OPERATOR_MAP.put("multiply", (x, y) -> x * y);
        OPERATOR_MAP.put("divide", (x, y) -> x / y);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome, choose your operator, would you like to add, subtract, multiply, or divide?");
        String typeofOperator = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the first number: ");
        int firstNumber = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the second number: ");
        int secondNumber = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(OPERATOR_MAP.get(typeofOperator).apply(firstNumber, secondNumber));
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course will not. Need to add return statement for each operator's method. I just wanted to add minimal changes to the original code.

Comment: :))) why not declare it as "void" ? btw, I like your answer!

Comment: Note: You could use `IntBinaryOperator` instead of `BiFunction<...>` which would avoid boxing.

Answer (score 2):

> in Java you can't pass in a parameter and use that parameter to call a
>   method

Well, you can start doing if/else and figure out which method should be called based on the operator-type. That said, it feels like an object-oriented approach would be cleaner:

We can define an `Operator` interface:

```
interface Operator {
    int call(int first, int second);
}
```

and then create classes that implement it: one per each operation:

```
class Add implements Operator {
    @Override
    public int call(int first, int second) {
        return first + second;
    }
}

class Subtract implements Operator {
    @Override
    public int call(int first, int second) {
        return first - second;
    }
}

class Multiply implements Operator {
    @Override
    public int call(int first, int second) {
        return first * second;
    }
}

class Divide implements Operator {
    @Override
    public int call(int first, int second) {
        return first / second;
    }
}
```

Now we need a factory that will receive the operator-type as an argument and which will create the related operator object respectively. One way to do it would be:

```
class OperatorFactory {
    static Operator build(String type) {
        Operator res;
        type = type.trim();
        switch (type) {
            case "add":
                res = new Add();
                break;
            case "subtract":
                res = new Subtract();
                break;
            case "multiply":
                res = new Multiply();
                break;
            case "divide":
                res = new Divide();
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(type);
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Let's see how the code works:

```
public class Methods {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome, choose your operator, would you like to add, subtract, multiply, or divide?");
        String typeofOperator = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the first number: ");
        int firstNumber = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the second number: ");
        int secondNumber = sc.nextInt();
        operator(typeofOperator, firstNumber, secondNumber);
    }

    static void operator(String typeOfOperator, int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
        Operator operator = OperatorFactory.build(typeOfOperator);
        int result = operator.call(firstNumber, secondNumber);
        System.out.println("result = " + result);
    }
}

class OperatorFactory {
    static Operator build(String type) {
        Operator res;
        type = type.trim();
        switch (type) {
            case "add":
                res = new Add();
                break;
            case "subtract":
                res = new Subtract();
                break;
            case "multiply":
                res = new Multiply();
                break;
            case "divide":
                res = new Divide();
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(type);
        }
        return res;
    }
}


interface Operator {
    int call(int first, int second);
}

class Add implements Operator {
    @Override
    public int call(int first, int second) {
        return first + second;
    }
}

class Subtract implements Operator {
    @Override
    public int call(int first, int second) {
        return first - second;
    }
}

class Multiply implements Operator {
    @Override
    public int call(int first, int second) {
        return first * second;
    }
}

class Divide implements Operator {
    @Override
    public int call(int first, int second) {
        return first / second;
    }
}
```

**Two comments:**

- As for "compactness": writing code should be concise indeed, that said, it *doesn't* mean that the shorter the code is - the better! 
  A code should be first and foremost readable as well as maintainable.
- Since the operator is passed as a string - there is no way to overload a method to do different things based on the type. One answer suggested reflection: while this is the only "compact" way I can think about - it is also a bad choice considering the following:

  1. debuggability
  2. maintainability
  3. code performance (reflection is done at runtime which makes it much slower than its alternatives)

Answer (score 1):

So you call the `operator` method, but you aren't calling a method from within that. You need to determine what the `typeofOperator` value is, then you should call the corresponding method associated with that. For example,

```
public static void operator( String typeofOperator, int firstNumber, int secondNumber){
    if( typeofOperator.equals("+") )
    {
        add(firstNumber, secondNumber);
    }
    else if( typeofOperator.equals("-") )
    {
        subtract(firstNumber, secondNumber);
    }
    else if( typeofOperator.equals("*") )
    {
        multiply(firstNumber, secondNumber);
    }
    else if( typeofOperator.equals("/") )
    {
        divide(firstNumber, secondNumber);
    }
    else
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(); //If we get here, we didn't get a valid argument.
}
```

As someone else mentioned, you need to change these methods to reflect the type of operation you are implying ( `add` should add the two numbers, `subtract` should subtract the two numbers, etc).

Comment: I get what you're saying @Orin but for the purposes of making the code as compact as possible I'm trying to see if there is a way to do this without using an if/else or a switch/case. Instead I want to take the user input and use that same input (assuming they typed in their answer correctly) to call a function using the parameters "typeofOperator".

Comment: @RubenVarela then you are going to want to use Reflection or method references as Chris Gong suggested below.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call Strings as methods. You have to use if or switch-case statements.

```
switch (typeOfOperator) {

case "add":
add(firstNumber, secondNumber); break;

case "subtract":
subtract(firstNumber, secondNumber); break;

case "multiply":
multiply(firstNumber, secondNumber); break;

case "divide":
divide(firstNumber, secondNumber); break;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest making a `HashMap` that stores the actual operator as the key and the method name as the value so that you can use it to access a specific method you want to invoke depending on the type of operator inputted by the user. Then, you can use reflection to call a method by a string containing the name of the method.

First, make the `HashMap` in your main method,

```
HashMap<String, String> operators = new HashMap<String, String>();
operators.put("+", "add");
operators.put("-", "subtract");
operators.put("*", "multiply");
operators.put("/", "divide");
```

Then, take the inputted operator to get the correct method name from the hashmap and call the method using reflection in your main method,

```
String chosenOperator = operators.get(typeOfOperator); //retrieves the method name
methods m = new methods(); //reflection
Method method = m.class.getMethod(chosenOperator);
method.invoke(m, firstNumber, secondNumber); //parameters are the object and
                                             //the method's parameters
```

**EDIT:** Instead of using reflection, you could use command patterns to hold the methods as objects and insert them into the `HashMap` instead of the names of the methods.

This is the **Java 8** solution using lambdas,

```
HashMap<String, Runnable> operators = new HashMap<String, Runnable>();
Runnable addMethod = () -> add(firstNumber, secondNumber);
Runnable subtractMethod = () -> subtract(firstNumber, secondNumber);
Runnable multiplyMethod = () -> multiply(firstNumber, secondNumber);
Runnable divideMethod = () -> divide(firstNumber, secondNumber);
operators.put("+", addMethod);
operators.put("-", subtractMethod);
operators.put("*", multiplyMethod);
operators.put("/", divideMethod);
operators.get(typeOfOperator).run();
```

By the way, you can do this to make it shorter,

```
HashMap<String, Runnable> operators = new HashMap<String, Runnable>();
operators.put("+", () -> add(firstNumber, secondNumber));
operators.put("-", () -> subtract(firstNumber, secondNumber));
operators.put("*", () -> multiply(firstNumber, secondNumber));
operators.put("/", () -> divide(firstNumber, secondNumber));
operators.get(typeOfOperator).run();
```

But I wanted to show that objects of type `Runnable` were being used.

Comment: Why reflection? This can be done without. Otherwise it's a good answer.

Comment: @John Vernee perhaps so, but this is just how I would go about without using if/else if statements

Comment: Yes, you can still use the hashmap, but reflection has to look up the method at runtime. You can wrap the functions in functors, (which is trivial with Java 8 `methods::add`, `methods::multiply` and `IntBinaryOperator`), and add those to the map. That way the methods can be resolved at compile time.

Comment: The problem is that `Runnable` takes 0 arguments, but the wrapped methods take 2. Where are you getting `firstNumber` and `secondNumber` from?

Comment: @JornVernee `firstNumber` and `secondNumber` are the two inputted numbers that OP has in his original code.

Answer (score 0):

This can be an alternative solution to if/else and switch methods.
Please notice the result() method moved away from every method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class methods {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome, choose your operator, would you like to add, subtract, multiply, or divide?");
        String typeofOperator = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the first number: ");
        int firstNumber = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the second number: ");
        int secondNumber = sc.nextInt();
        operator(typeofOperator, firstNumber, secondNumber);
    }

    public static void operator(String typeofOperator, int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
        java.lang.reflect.Method method;
        Object returnedValue = null;
        try {
            method = methods.class.getDeclaredMethod(typeofOperator, int.class, int.class);
            returnedValue = method.invoke(null, firstNumber, secondNumber);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        result((Integer) returnedValue);
    }

    public static int add(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
        int answer = firstNumber + secondNumber;
        return answer;
    }
    public static int subtract(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
        int answer = firstNumber - secondNumber;
        return answer;
    }
    public static int multiply(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
        int answer = firstNumber * secondNumber;
        return answer;
    }
    public static int divide(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
        int answer = firstNumber / secondNumber;
        return answer;
    }
    public static void result(int result) {
        System.out.println("This is the result: " + result);
    }
}
```